Efficient construction of Hermitian block matrix
I need to construct large Hermitian matrices $H$, which can be built out of blocks. The matrix $H$ is of total size $Lx\times Ly$, with blocks of size $Ly$. For $Lx=5,\,Ly=3$ and $L=2$ (which is the number of blocks $B_L$ in the diagonal), it looks like
$$
H=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 B_L & -\mathbb{1} & 0 & 0 & A \\
 -\mathbb{1} & B_L & -\mathbb{1} & 0 & 0 \\
 0  & -\mathbb{1} & B_R & -\mathbb{1} & 0 \\
 0  & 0 & -\mathbb{1} & B_R & -\mathbb{1} \\
 A^\dagger & 0 & 0 & -\mathbb{1} & B_R 
\end{array}
\right).$$

The block matrices $B_{L,R}$ are Hermitian. Here is an attempt (with simplified matrices):
(* Define the block matrices B_{L,R}. Note that the Block[...] is overkill, 
but I need it to pass through other arguments for the actual matrices *)

B[Ly_, t_] :=
  Block[{M}, 
   M = ToeplitzMatrix[PadRight[{2., -1.}, Ly]] // N;
   M[[1, Ly]] = -Exp[2.\[Pi] I t];
   M[[Ly, 1]] = -Conjugate[Exp[2.\[Pi] I t]]];
   M
  ];

(* Define the block Hermitian matrix H *)

H[Lx_, Ly_, L_, tL_, tR_, t_] :=
  Block[{M, BL, BR, A, id},
   
   pad = PadRight[{BR, -id}, Lx - 1] // N;
   col = Join[pad, {A}];
   row = Join[pad, {Conjugate[A]}];
   M = ToeplitzMatrix[row, col];
   
   Do[
    M[[i, i]] = BL;
   , {i, 1, L}];
   
   BL = B[Ly, tL];
   BR = B[Ly, tR];
   id = IdentityMatrix[Ly] // N;
   A = -Exp[2\[Pi] I t] id;
   
   M = M // N // ArrayFlatten;
   
   M
  ];

Unfortunately, the code above is very slow, and very inefficient memory-wise (I need to access sizes around $500\times500$). Is there a smarter way to construct this matrix $H$?

Edit
I found that this code performs quite well:
B[Ly_, t_] :=
  Block[{M},
   M = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 2., Band[{1, 2}] -> -1., 
       Band[{2, 1}] -> -1.}, {Ly, Ly}] // N;
   M[[1, Ly]] = -Chop[Exp[2.\[Pi] I t]];
   M[[Ly, 1]] = -Chop[Exp[-2.\[Pi] I t]];
   M
   ];

Kxy[Lx_, Ly_, L_, tL_, tR_, t_]] :=
  Block[{H, Hdiag, Hoffdiag, rulesDiag, BL, BR},
   BL = B[Ly, tL];
   BR = B[Ly, tR];
   
   rulesDiag = 
    Join[{#, #} -> BL &/@Range[L], {#, #} -> BR &/@Range[L + 1, Lx]];
   
   Hoffdiag = 
    SparseArray[
    {Band[{1, Ly + 1}] -> -1., Band[{Ly + 1, 1}] -> -1., 
     Band[{1, Ly (Lx - 1) + 1}] -> -Chop[Exp[2.\[Pi] I t]],
     Band[{Ly (Lx - 1) + 1, 1}] -> -Chop[Exp[-2.\[Pi] I t]]}
    ,{Lx Ly, Lx Ly}];
   
   Hdiag = SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[rulesDiag]//ArrayFlatten;
   
   H = Hdiag + Hoffdiag;
   
   H // N
   ];
```


Have you tried working with sparse arrays? They are likely much more efficient in your very sparse situation.

As a start, B[n_Integer /; n >= 3, t_] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 2, Band[{1, 2}] -> -1, Band[{2, 1}] -> -1, {1, n} -> -Exp[2 π I t], {n, 1} -> -Exp[-2 π I t]}, {n, n}]

I was indeed working with SparseArray before, but it seemed even worse in terms of speed and memory..

Does this post help you?

Yes and no :). The KroeneckerProduct trick is nice but I am having difficulties applying it to my problem since I have an unequal number of block matrices $B_L$ and $B_R$ on the diagonal.

I have found a better way! I'll edit my post. PS: the latex matrix gives me some trouble, I cannot post my edit because it return an error of "formatting". I have to put the matrix between code quotes.
